# How does an ISP authenticate modem/router connection?

Tags: networking, router, internet, network-adapter, isp

When we don’t pay the bill how will ISP disable Internet? Is it done by disabling connections to the particular hardware (MAC) address of the router Or by disabling connection to the hardware port corresponding to the router? Or something else?

Comment: Different ISP do it differently. Update your question with ISP you want to know about.

Comment: I use an ISP called asianet broadband. I dont think it operates outside India.

Comment: ISPs will typically have an index that relates circuit IDs on their MDF to a street address. There will also be mappings for how these particular circuit IDs relate to ports on the DSLAM or CMTS. In their CRM, they'll be able to see whose billing is behind (probably have automatic reports for this) and when it gets too long, they'll trace the street address for that account to a specific port and they'll down or suspend the port, or break it in some way (different systems do this in very different ways). It'll rarely have to do with anything plugged in at your end.

Comment: @MaQleod - When you say circuit IDs do you mean phone phone lines? What does MDF refer to? Do you mean so say the ISPs exchange?

Comment: @Motivated, MDF is the main distribution frame, it is an entity to which the bulk of circuits to various pieces of equipment terminate into blocks that are all interconnected using cross-connect wiring along the frame. There is a set of blocks specific to the pairs that go out to the street and are all assigned IDs that map to the street address in a database.

Comment: There are then sets of blocks for the Dslam, OEs go out to the office equipment (5ess switching system or similar) and CPs goes to the cable pairs (the blocks mentioned above). The 5ess switches have their own blocks there too. When they connect your dsl service, they pull your cross connect from your circuit ID on the cable blocks going to the 5ess and add cross connects to pins (circuit ids) on the OE and CP blocks of the dslam and then link that chain in the database. That gives them the full physical path.

Comment: @MaQleod - To be fair, i did not fully understand the answer. Is there a diagram that illustrates your comment? Do you mean to say that a circuit or a phone line terminates at a main distribution frame. These connections are plugged into blocks / segments on the main distribution frame. Each of these blocks are assigned an identifier which are mapped to a street address. Do you also mean to say in addition to the main distribution frame, there are blocks for DSLAM? Do these connect to the main distribution frame? What are OE and CP?

Comment: @Motivated, https://imgur.com/a/U5yATjH. So think of the MDF as the place where every individual port is wired out to in the form of blocks with pins. These blocks are typically 200 pin blocks (both front and back), the equipment wires into the back and cross-connects get wired in the front (all are wire-wrapped connections). They are 200 pin, but 100 circuit (wired in pairs, Tx/Rx). So you'd use cross-connects to create the path the circuit takes through the central office. Each post set (tx/rx) on each block has an individual ID marking it to the equipment end-point.

Comment: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_uKfqyv-XFYk/ShDQ1c6d5FI/AAAAAAAAAB0/dt-_CV3OkaQ/s1600/Frame01.jpg is a typical example of an MDF from the front. The wires coming out the top of the blocks are the cross-connects. You can't see the feed cables as they are tied under the bars and go into the back of the blocks (they come in at the top of the frame in the back, get tied down the back and are then tied in going into the blocks at the back).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different ISP's would have different methods depending on their equipment and type of service, but at the end of the day it's all routers and switches of one sort or another, so they just disable your route until you pay the bill. You might even still be able to ping their equipment in some cases. Whether it's a Wimax box or a Cisco switch it's still done the same way.

I don't think many would do it using the mac address of your router unless they own it.

So for instance some Wimax providers use the mac address of the receiver, because they provide and configure these themselves and a customer cannot just go out and buy one, plug it in and expect it to work.

But adsl providers probably wouldn't because the customer can (normally) put in their own router.

Comment: Cant agree more, there would be little point of doing it by the mac address when you can A, clone it and B just change the device. Either case you would immediately be back online, this doesnt happen because they close your switch/port whatever it is on their end. Actually some ISP's don't even do that, they just route your service to a server which just tells you you have not paid or need to top up whatever the case may be.